# Footer not sticky

Tags: html, css

I'm learning now CSS and i'm creating a portfolio page as part of it.
I've created  this page: [link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/maoruliel/pen/mXzjoJ)

The thing is, the footer is not sticks to the bottom of the page, can some one tell me how can i fix it? so it will be after the `<div id="contact">`

Iv'e noticed that when I do put it in the `<div class="content">` it does work, I tried to figure out why and I didn't got it.

Thanks.

CSS & HTML are here:

```css
html,
body,
main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Alef";
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
}

nav {
  width: 960px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}

a {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.active {
  color: #004cc6;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #f9fafc;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content > div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#home {
  background: #0f5fe0;
}
#portfolio {
  background: #129906;
}
#about {
  background-color: #a00411;
}
#contact {
  background-color: black;
}

:target:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 70px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin: -70px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;

  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">My Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="home">
      <p>#home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <p>#about</p>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio">
      <p>#portfolio</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <p>#contact</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  Fotter
</footer>
```

Comment: use `position:fixed` and `bottom:0` to the `footer`

Comment: you mean sticky like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zrmawa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height: 50%;` from `.content > div` if you want to put footer just after contact.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQwOeR)

---

If you want to stick footer to the bottom of the browser window, then add this to your css:

`footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
}`

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpeOVe)

Comment: I meant to put it after contact, not with `position: fixed;`.
Is there any way to keep the `height` parameter ant still put it after the `contact`

Answer (score 0):

Change footer value like below

```
 footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;

      background-color: #dbdbdb;
      text-align: center;
      height: 70px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use vh instead of percentage to set the min-height of main, then you need to remove the height

```
.main {
  min-height: 100vh; // Change as per your requirement
}
```